# Visualforce <style> tag outputting as text in PDF

Tags: visualforce, pdf, style

Here is the beginning of my visualforce page:

```
    <apex:page StandardController="Project__c" extensions="projectToPDFController" renderAs="pdf" standardStylesheets="false">
<style> body { font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS'; } </style>
```

And this is how it is rendering:
[image]

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

***Edit

Here another example with less included on the page:

```
<apex:page StandardController="Project__c" renderAs="pdf" standardStylesheets="false">
<style> body { font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS'; } </style>

    Output
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: have you wrapped your css in a <style> ?  It is just assuming that is text rather than markup

Comment: Yes- and edited my post so it properly renders here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The renderer only accepts style formats in the `head` section of the page:

```
<apex:page StandardController="Project__c" 
           extensions="projectToPDFController" 
           renderAs="pdf"
           showHeader="false"
           applyHtmlTag="false" 
           standardStylesheets="false">
    <html>
        <head>
            <style> body { font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS'; } </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <!-- main content here -->
        </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

You might find it easier to use [apex:stylesheet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_stylesheet.htm) so you don't need to include all the extra header information in your code, although this requires uploading your CSS as a Static Resource in order to use it.

Comment: This works- thank you very much for the explanation